# How to annotate rails engine models with annotate_models gem?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines, rails-models, annotate

I can annotate my models using

```
annotate --exclude tests,fixtures,factories,serializers
```

How can I annotate models inside my rails engine? I tried using

```
annotate --model-dir ../your-engine-name/app/models
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The engine, if it's installed as a gem, probably isn't located at `../your-engine-name`

Try:

```
--model-dir `bundle show your_engine_name`/app/models
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the path issue. However, my migrations are present inside the engine. When I run the given command, it gives error Unable to annotate, cannot load a model from <model path in engine>

Comment: Sorry, not sure, I'm not actually familiar with the annotate_models gem.  You might file an Issue on the annotate_models repo and see if the developers can help you. Or try actually going into the engine source directory and running the `annotate` command from there. `cd \`bundle show your_engine_name\``